# How deeply to test SQL injection vulnerability

Tags: security, sql-injection, code-injection

Image the following situation:

I know(I can see) in the code that before querying to DB using an input field parameter, there is a function which escapes all chars. Pseudo code:

`escape_all_chars(input_field_variable)`

Is there any point of testing multiple SQL queries in the input field rather than the simplest one?

I mean is it possible to have a complex SQL injection query that can somehow pass the `escape_all_chars` prevention?

*Note*: By *complex* SQL query I am not talking about complex in the way of a many character long query like writing 100k symbols. I am talking about SQL query with complex logic in it.

Comment: `sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id="+escape_all_chars(input_field_variable);` - here you are, a terrible complex SQL injection.

Comment: The problem with "escaping" is that people do not understand what it's for and confuse it with something else.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I got what you meant. You are right, I have wrong understanding. Thanks :)